# "CreateTextureFromCVTextureCache" Error on Unity3d IOS build

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, metal

So I have been working on an IOS app built-in unity3d. When I try and push the app to 
my iPhone in Xcode I receive a "Use of undeclared identifier 'CreateTextureFromCVTextureCache' when
doing the build.

The full code snippet is in the link below:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZDb0pbHCfI8zmroe9F34Pk_EIt2C585S/view?usp=sharing

I hope you can help.

Comment: Hi The project is built from unity3d. So trying to figure out if the error is coming from unity3d or xcode.

Comment: Here is the code:   videoSampling.cvTextureCacheTexture = 

CreateTextureFromCVTextureCache(_videoSampling.cvTextureCache, pixelBuffer, w, h);

Comment: /IOSBUILD2/Libraries/Plugins/IOS/CustomVideoPlayer.mm:356:56: Use of undeclared identifier 'CreateTextureFromCVTextureCache'; did you mean 'CreateBGRA32TextureFromCVTextureCache'?

Answer (score 0):

'CreateTextureFromCVTextureCache' is deprecated in Metal API, use 'CreateBGRA32TextureFromCVTextureCache' instead.

Answer (score -1):

After further investigation I noticed that the CreateTextureFromCVTextureCache class is deprecated for Metal graphics api. Hope This help others.